# Running a single migration returns nothing to migrate

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

This question is been asked many times; ok sure but as we all say, "it works on my machine". Could someone explain the possible reasons for when I ran

`php artisan migrate --path=/database/2017----.php`, I got

> Nothing to migrate.

Variations ran:

```
php artisan migrate --path="/database/2017----.php"
php artisan migrate --path="/database/2017----"
php artisan migrate --path=/database/2017----
```

I have that file in my migration. `php artisan migrate:status` shows it pending

Im on Laravel 5.

Comment: Why are you trying to single migrations? They all work together, what happens when you just do `php artisan migrate`?

Comment: I guess path means path, so make a folder and put your migration in it, then use path switch.

Comment: I think you missed the migrations folder `/database/migrations/2017----.php`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update your `migration command` :

```
php artisan migrate --path=/database/2017----.php
```

**To**

```
php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/2017----.php
```